Firebase Analytics KMP initialization
I'm trying to develop a multiplatform library using the https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk but I'm getting stuck on the firebase initialization, in both Android/iOS platforms.
Below my implementation:
/**
 * Analytics SDK entry point.
 */
object Analytics {

    /**
     * Start the Analytics SDK.
     */
    fun initialize(platformInitializer: Platform) {
        platformInitializer.initializeFirebase()
    }
}

interface Platform {
    fun initializeFirebase()
}

import android.content.Context
import dev.gitlive.firebase.Firebase
import dev.gitlive.firebase.initialize

class AndroidPlatform(private val context: Context) : Platform {
    override fun initializeFirebase() {
        Firebase.initialize(context)
    }
}

import dev.gitlive.firebase.Firebase
import platform.UIKit.UIApplication
import dev.gitlive.firebase.initialize

class iOSPlatform(private val application: UIApplication) : Platform {
    override fun initializeFirebase() {
        Firebase.initialize(application)
    }
}

And in the android application onCreate:
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Analytics.initialize(AndroidPlatform(this))
    }
}

I am receiving a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldev/gitlive/firebase/Firebase; and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
